# Передать функцию в конструктор класса JS

Tags: javascript

Нужно передать в конструктор класса функцию, которую нужно вызвать внутри класса. Когда я вызываю функцию checkout(), получаю сообщение, что discount не функция. Как сделать, чтобы функции "попадали" в класс, оттуда брали значение amount и при вызове checkout() возвращалось верное значение?

```
class Discount {
    constructor (discount) {
        this.discount = discount
        this.amount = 0
    }
    checkout() {
        return this.discount(this.amount)
    }
    setAmount(amount) {
        this.amount = amount
    }
}

function bronzeCard(amount) {
    return amount * 0.9
}

function silverCard(amount) {
    return amount * 0.8
}
function goldenCard(amount) {
    return amount * 0.7
}

let bronzeCustomer = new Discount(bronzeCard())
let silverCustomer = new Discount(silverCard())
let goldenCustomer = new Discount(goldenCard())

bronzeCustomer.setAmount(500)
console.log(bronzeCustomer.checkout())

silverCustomer.setAmount(500)
console.log(silverCustomer.checkout())

goldenCustomer.setAmount(500)
console.log(goldenCustomer.checkout())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Надо добавлять ссылку на функцию, а вы передаёте результат работы функции, т.к. `()` запускает её:

```
let bronzeCustomer = new Discount(bronzeCard)
let silverCustomer = new Discount(silverCard)
let goldenCustomer = new Discount(goldenCard)
```